# How to set environment variables dynamically for command?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, associative-array, template

I would like to use some kind of minimalistic template engine with pure bash and `envsubst`:

```bash
user@host:~$ env -i FOO=foo BAR="bar baz" envsubst '$FOO,$BAR' \
  <<< 'Hello "$FOO" and "$BAR"!'
Hello "foo" and "bar baz"!
```

Above works, but only contains static variables.

Now let's assume environment variables are given dynamically, like with an associative array:

```bash
declare -A MY_ENV=([FOO]=foo [BAR]="bar baz")
```

Parsing the array key-value pairs only works for environment values without whitespaces (errors):

```bash
env -i \
  $(for k in "${!MY_ENV[@]}"; do printf "%s=%s " $k "${MY_ENV[$k]}"; done) \ 
  envsubst #...
```

Trying to wrap environment values by quotes (note  `'%s'`  instead of `%s` ) also errors:

```bash
env -i \
  $(for k in "${!MY_ENV[@]}"; do printf "%s='%s' " $k "${MY_ENV[$k]}"; done) \ 
  envsubst #...
```

Output of `set -x`:
<s>Reason: `set -x` shows that the argument for `env` becomes one giant string</s>:

```bash
+ env -i 'FOO='\''foo'\''' 'BAR='\''bar' 'baz'\''' envsubst #...
env: ‘baz'’: No such file or directory
```

I must have missed a shell escape lession (again...). How might I rewrite last example to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [[BashFAQ/050]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- you have to use an array to ensure each `"key=value"` pair is properly quoted.

```bash
vars=()
for k in "${!MY_ENV[@]}"; do
    vars+=( "$k=${MY_ENV[$k]}" )
done
env -i "${vars[@]}" envsubst '$FOO,$BAR' <<< 'Hello "$FOO" and "$BAR"!'
```

```
Hello "foo" and "bar baz"!
```

Notice how I'm not injecting any extra quote characters.

---

Extending to so we don't have to hard-code the variable names:

```bash
keys=( "${!MY_ENV[@]}" )
printf -v varnames ',%s' "${keys[@]/#/'$'}"

env -i "${vars[@]}" envsubst "${varnames#,}" <<< 'Hello "$FOO" and "$BAR"!'

# or without the `varnames` temp var
env -i "${vars[@]}" envsubst "$(IFS=,; echo "${keys[*]/#/'$'}")" <<< 'Hello "$FOO" and "$BAR"!'
```

Comment: Fantastic! Learned a lot, thank you. After reading [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), solution became clear.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to `export` each key-value pair one-by-one and execute `envsubst` afterwards:

```
for k in "${!MY_ENV[@]}"; do export $k="${MY_ENV[$k]}"; done 
envsubst '$FOO,$BAR' <<< 'Hello "$FOO" and "$BAR"!'
#Hello "foo" and "bar baz"!
```

The code might be placed inside a subshell to prevent polluting the current environment.

---

(PS: Still curious, why dynamically building arguments after `env` in original post did not work - any help appreciated.)